# How to create GSP taglib without Grails

Tags: groovy, taglib, gsp

We can use GSP without Grails, just mapping servlet `groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet`.
And what about TagLibs?

[Here are](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.3%20Tag%20Libraries) docs about using TagLibs with Grails - we should just add class to `grails-app/taglib` folder.

Is it possible to create custom GSP tag without Grails? And if it possible, even more important question, how exactly can it be done?

**UPDATE:** it looks like there is a separate Grails Plugin for it - https://github.com/houbie/gsp-taglib. So the question actually boils down to how we can
use code from this plugin I guess.

Comment: Can't you just build a regular jsp tag lib but just write it in groovy: ie http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPTags5.html#74701

Comment: this would be a tag lib which suits for asp, not gsp.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Are you saying you want to use a groovy/java taglib in a Microsoft ASP (Active Server Pages) site? That seems difficult/impossible, or at least more trouble than it's worth. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @mlathe custom tags works in `jsp` not in `gsp`, sorry of the typo  - now I believe it makes sense )))

Comment: hmm... Are you sure that's not supported? I don't see why that wouldn't work: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Using-a-JSP-tag-from-GSP-td1351642.html

Comment: @mlathe in Grails realization it is supported, not in `groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet` - that is exactly what this question is about))) don't confuse grails and groovy

Comment: I guess your question is not clear. Good luck.

Comment: >Is it possible to create custom GSP tag without Grails? And if it possible, even more important question, how exactly can it be done? - honestly I don't know what exactly is not clear in this statement) but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5657 full GSPs independent of Grails is (as of September 2012) a feature yet to come. Some minimal versions have been done though