# How to separate enriched GSP engine from Grails framework

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

This question [relates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259332/how-to-create-gsp-taglib-without-grails) to my previous question, but is actually wider.
So, it turns out that  GSP in Grails and GSP, using groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet
are quiet different things.

Grails provide set of additional tags and mechanisms which are absent in "pure" GSP.
The question is - how can I separate GSP functionality from Grails as much as possible.
By "as much as possible" I mean that there are actually some features in Grails GSP which makes sense only in grails (like binding to controllers). Nevertheless, all that nice things like gsp:inlcude, custom tags and so on and so on - is there a cheap and elegant way to use them separately?

Answer (score 1):

Like often with Grails, you have to go deeper in the stack. Here you fall on Spring MVC framework.

Spring MVC allows you to use [most templating frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516/template-engines-for-spring-framework), but you'll have to deal with its [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html). Spring MVC needs a ModelAndView object, and [Grails can return it](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.3%20Models%20and%20Views) :

```
def index = { // get some books 
   def favoriteBooks = ...
   return new ModelAndView("/book/list", [ bookList : favoriteBooks ]) 
}
```

For the moment,using GSP as first class objects is an [open issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7670), and there is a nice blog post that [describe the problem](http://nlabrot.blogspot.com/2011/02/grails-view-as-spring-mvc-view.html).

My conclusion is that there is still some workaround, and if you try something on your own, it may be overturned in a future Grails release.